# Content not displaying while using wagtailtrans package on the page

Tags: django, django-templates, wagtail

In my models.py file I have defined **StandardPage class** to which I want to add trans`enter code here`lations.In this class I have defined these:

```
class StandardPage(TranslatablePage,Page):

    introduction = models.TextField(
        help_text='Text to describe the page',
        blank=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        help_text='Landscape mode only; horizontal width between 1000px and 3000px.'
    )
    video_url = models.URLField(null=True,blank=True)
    body = StreamField([
        ( 'main_content',blocks.ListBlock(BaseStreamBlock()  ,label = 'content') )]
        , blank=True,
           null=True,
         verbose_name="Page body" )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('introduction', classname="full"),
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('video_url'),   ]

 @property
 def standard_page(self):
    return self.get_parent().specific

 def get_context(self, request):
    language = request.LANGUAGE_CODE
    standard_page = request.site.standard_page
    pages = TranslatablePage.objects.live().filter(language__code=language).specific().child_of(standard_page)
    context['pages'] = self.standard_page
    return context
```

While template base.html contains:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load wagtailtrans_tags wagtailcore_tags  wagtailuserbar  %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>
            {% block title_suffix %}
                {% if self.seo_title %}{{ self.seo_title }}{% else %}{{ self.title }}{% endif %}
            {% endblock %}
        </title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        {# Global stylesheets #}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/mysite.css' %}">
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{% static 'fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{% static 'css/streamfields.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        {% block extra_css %}
            {# Override this in templates to add extra stylesheets #}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
        {% wagtailuserbar %}
{% get_translations page homepage_fallback=False include_self=False as translations %}
{% for language, page in translations.items %}
<link rel="alternate" href="{{ page.full_url }}" hreflang="{{ language.code }}">
{% endfor %}
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
        {# Global javascript #}

        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/mysite.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

        {% block extra_js %}
            {# Override this in templates to add extra javascript #}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

and my template 'standard_page.html' contains:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}
 {% block content%}
{% include "base/include/header.html" %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                {{ page.body }}
            </div>
 </div>
        </div>
{% endblock  %}
```

Not rendering content on the page.It's showing **Welcome to your new Wagtail site!** even though I published all the languages of a particular page.But the title of the page is displaying in different languages mentioned
I am new to django & wagtail. How to rectify this, not getting.
Any help?

Comment: What are you doing in `get_context`? Why do you replace `page` with the parent page? Did you follow all getting started steps of the wagtailtrans documentation? Do you expect `{{ page.body }}` to render a streamfield? Read the docs on Streamfield template rendering: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/topics/streamfield.html#template-rendering

Comment: Thanks ,now it's showing the content

Comment: The concept of StackOverflow is that you ask good questions and get good answers in a way that others with the same question are helped too. How did I answer your question? FYI: It's okay to answer your own question. ;)